# Нужны запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

> Впереди, в черноте леса, куда он смотрел, послышался пронзительный вопль, и в следующую секунду в небо(,) над кронами деревьев(,) ударил столп огня.

Интонационного выделения нет. Поисковик выдал кучу «в небе над деревьями» без запятых.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Впереди, в черноте леса, куда он смотрел, послышался пронзительный вопль, и в следующую секунду в небо над кронами деревьев ударил столп огня.

"В небо над кронами деревьев" - неоднородные обстоятельства, идет сужение значения: в часть неба над кронами деревьев.

"Над кронами деревьев" - это обстоятельство можно представить как уточняющее по желанию автора, но в этом предложении делать это не имеет смысла.

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно, что такое "небо над кронами деревьев", но запятые не нужны.

Comment: «Небо над кронами деревьев» — это взгляд вверх человека, который стоит посреди леса. Такое сочетание некорректно?

Comment: Столб ударил (куда?) в небо.
Столб виден (где?) над кронами.

А у вас это "куда" и "где" смешалось.

Comment: Cовершенно  верно  -  столб !